# Error: Out of memory in AWS Aurora MySQL + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-sdk-nodejs

Getting Out of memory when importing 100,000 data (20MB file) to database.

I am using **"db.t4g.medium"** aurora mysql instance which has **4 GB ram**.

**Error Details :-**

```
Error: Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
    at PromiseConnection.query (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:93:22)
    at Function.getQueryResult (/var/task/wpcn-connect-to-rds/rdsProxyDBManager.js:10:49)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/wpcn-connect-to-rds/index.js:48:21) {
  code: 'ER_OUT_OF_RESOURCES',
  errno: 1041
```

Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space","code":"ER_OUT_OF_RESOURCES","message":"Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space","errno":1041

**> Is there any way to solve this issue without increasing the RAM or instance type?**

I am Using javascript/nodejs programming for connecting to mysql :-

```
static async getQueryResult (secret, query){       
    const connection = await mysql2.createConnection(secret);   
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.query(query);       
    connection.end();
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': rows
    }
}
```

> secret = {
> host,
> user: username,
> password: password,
> port: port,
> waitForConnections: true,
> multipleStatements: true,
> connectionLimit: 10,
> queueLimit: 0
> }

*The file that we are importing has 100,000 insert statements like shown below:-*

INSERT INTO table1 (id,subject,description,progress,hours,startdt,duedt,private) VALUES(null,'test','1','0','0','2022-08-02 00:00:00.000','2022-08-02 00:00:00.000','1');

INSERT INTO table1 (id,subject,description,progress,hours,startdt,duedt,private) VALUES(null,'XSS','','1','1','2022-08-02 00:00:00.000','2022-08-02 00:00:00.000','0');

Comment: We need to see the DDL for the relevant tables and the full query, not the code executing the query.

Comment: There is an sql file that i am uploading. It consist of 100,000 insert query.    

Around 90k - 95k data are entered each time we try to do the import operation. (count varies between 90 - 95k)

Comment: How are you processing the multiple statements? Are you trying to send all (90 - 95k) inserts statements in one `connection.query` call? That would definitely be the source of your problem, if it is the case! You should be sending them individually using a prepared statement, or possibly in small batches. Better still would be to rewrite them as batched multi-inserts.

Comment: prepared statement might not work in my scenario because it will be different table name with different column structure each time we do the import.

Comment: You could still parse the queries and then reconstruct them as prepared statements but if the queries are from a _trusted_ source and you are fine with running them as they are, that is your call. You still need to split them up to run them either individually or as batches. Or, you could change your approach. and use the mysql client to run the queries.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to solve this issue without increasing the RAM or instance type?

You can modify the instance to a different instance type with more RAM, just for the duration of the data loading. The way to do that with the least disruption would be (a) add a new bigger instance to the cluster, (b) do failover to make that new instance the writer, (c) do the data load with no worries about out-of-memory or taking excessive time, (d) failover back to the original T instance, (e) delete the bigger instance.

T instances are memory-constrained, more than with RDS because Aurora is running more management software alongside the database. For that reason, they're recommended for dev/test but not production. See here for best practices when working on such small instances with Aurora:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.BestPractices.html#AuroraMySQL.BestPractices.T2Medium